# Is it safe to delete dead symlinks on OS/X?

Tags: macos, symbolic-link

Running a routine check on OS/X:

```
sudo find -L / -type l
```

reveals **a lot** of broken symbolic links. Many of them are in /Library or ~/Library. Quite some there in application settings.

Is it safe to delete those? (And why are they there?)

Some of them:

`/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-urw-aliases.conf
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/XPCServices
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ParsecUI.framework/XPCServices
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TracesOSKit.framework/TracesOSKit
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/vCard.framework/XPCServices`

Comment: Any examples of which paths specifically?

Comment: @SimonSheehan samples addes